# Symfony2 : How do I render a resultset into HTML grouping records in the output

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, group-by, twig

I have a Doctrine query as follows...

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->select('s, csr, c')
            ->Join('s.classesreference', 'csr')
            ->Join('csr.Class', 'c')
            ->where('c.id = :id and csr.SpellLevel = :level')
            ->setParameter('level', $level)
            ->setParameter('id', $Class->getId())
            ->orderBy('s.Name','ASC')
            ->orderBy('csr.SpellLevel')
            ->getQuery();
```

In my Twig template I'd like to display the results of this query in a nested unordered list.

```
<ul>
    <li>Level 0
        <ul>
            <!-- Level zero spells here -->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 1
        <ul>
            <!-- Level one spells here -->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 2
        <ul>
            <!-- Level two spells here -->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 3
        <ul>
            <!-- Level three spells here -->
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I just can't figure out how to do this in twig from the returned result set (essentially an array of `Spell` objects)

`classesreference` is a reference table between `Spell` and `CharacterClass` that also contains a field for the spell level when used by the referenced `CharacterClass` record.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you group by spellLevel, you'll only have one result per level? So your first level will be in $result[0] and so on. Maybe you can add more information about your data structure.

Comment: I may be misuderstanding groupby ... I understood it to collect records with the same value together in the result set with the sortby then applying to these groups.  How would you suggest I achieve the results I want from the question?

Comment: Ok, after some reading I was misuderstanding GroupBy ... I still can't figure out how to do what I want to do though.. updated question to reflect my increase in understanding.

Comment: An easy way to get started is to simply iterate over the $spells array in your controller and generate 4 new arrays each containing just one level.  Pass these 4 arrays to your template.  There are of course better ways to accomplish this but this will get you going.

Comment: Unfortunately there are currently a lot more spell levels than 4 and possibly more to add in the future so I need a solution that will work for any number of spell levels.

Comment: Same approach only use an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after the misunderstanding of groupBy is fixed, let's dive into this one ;)

First, what you want to achieve is a two-dimensional array like this:

```
array(
    0 => array('Spell1', 'Spell4'),
    1 => array(),
    2 => array('Spell3'),
    3 => array('Spell2'),
);
```

The first array would contain every spell level and an array of spells.

This cannot be done with MySQL alone. MySQL returns rows, so there is no way to write a query which will give you the perfect array. So, what you want to do is write a query which gives you back all spells with their level. As I cannot fully grasp your table design, the following needs some work, but it might get you an idea:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->select('s, csr, c')
            ->Join('s.classesreference', 'csr')
            ->Join('csr.Class', 'c')
            ->where('c.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $Class->getId())
            ->orderBy('s.Name','ASC')
            ->orderBy('csr.SpellLevel')
            ->getQuery();
$resultArray = $qb->getArrayResult();

$spellLevelArray = array();
foreach($resultArray AS $result) {
    $spellLevel = $result['spelllevel'];
    $spellLevelArray[$spellLevel][] = $result['spell'];
}
```

As you can see, a foreach is used to iterate over each row (which is one spell) and add the spell to the inner array corresponding to the level. As said, you might need to change some stuff (like the spelllevel and what you store inside the array), but the overall idea should be clear.

Comment: Thanks for this... it is helpful ... is there no way with Doctrine2 to pull something like this out using DQL instead of writing the loop myself?

Comment: Well, the way you could do it with an ORM would be to add a method to your Class object, something like `getSpellsForLevel($level)` and then iterate over all spells and give back the spells for that level. Or you could query the classesreference class for the specific level and class and iterate over those.

Comment: Marked as the answer.  Thanks. I was hoping there would be a DQL statement that could bring the results back in the array format you describe above.  Thanks for the help anyway.